# How to reliably inherit from classes having no data members?

Tags: c++, c++17

A lot of my classes inherit from some classes that provide useful functions and impose virtual functions, but have no data members. For example:

```
class Printable
{
  public:
    virtual ~Printable() noexcept = default;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const = 0;
    std::string toString() const
    {
      std::ostringstream oss;
      this->print(oss);
      return oss.str();
    }
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Printable const& p)
{
  p.print(out);
  return out;
}
```

When a common class inherits from it (in order to easily have the functionality), I don't have to worry if I have something to save/load when archiving, if I have something to swap in the parent class. But it's not clear that I haven't. It requires an understanding of the parent class hierarchy, or to read the documentation of the class.

**Is there a more reliable way (at compile-time or runtime) to be sure that the parent classes have no non-static data members?**

```
class Foo : public Printable
{
  private:
    Some members;
  public:
    // Constructors...
    virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const
    {
      out << Some::printer(this->members);
    }
    void swap(Foo& foo) noexcept
    {
      // Hmmm... Have I to swap someting in Printable ???
      this->members.swap(foo.members);
    }
    void save(Archive& ar) const
    {
      // Hmmm... Have I to save someting from Printable ???
      this->members.save(ar);
    }
};
```

In my case, I think that `std::is_empty` doesn't work, because the class has virtual functions.

I could define only an empty constructor in `Printable`, and forbid the copy (like below). Then the message is more clear that there is no data to manage in the parent class. But then I lose the easy way to define default constructors:

```
class Printable
{
  public:
    Printable() noexcept = default;
    Printable(Printable const&) = delete;
    Printable& operator=(Printable const&) = delete;
    virtual ~Printable() noexcept = default;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const = 0;
};
class Foo : public Printable
{
  private:
    Some members;
  public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo const&) = default; // Error: no copy constructor in the parent class
    // Instead I have to write:
    Foo(Foo const& foo) : Printable(), members(foo.members) {}
    // Quite boring if there is many members...
};
```

**Is there any other way?**

Comment: This is one reason why you write documentation: To tell users of your classes what they do, and what they contain (if anything). If the documentation doesn't mention anything about saving, swapping etc., including there's no related member functions or interfaces, then it's not needed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude documentation is oh-so-nineties. We do not do documentation anymore. The code should either be self-explanatory, or contain security mechanisms to safeguard proper operation and prevent misuse. This question is about adding such a security mechanism.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: having a security mechanism in the code using the class is also a security if someone have to change de parent class. If it becomes necessary to matter about members of the parent class, I want an error if I forgot to do it anywhere. Editing the documentation is not enough ^_^'

Comment: I'd add a `swap` and `save` function to `Printable` as well; as long as there are no members, they just wouldn't do anything. You'll need to remember to call them, but you'd have to remember doing any other test as well. This approach is safer than any kind of `sizeof` test, as `Printable` might get added members that are irrelevant for e.g. saving, maybe even for swapping. Additionally you don't have to change inheriting classes if indeed (relevant) variables are added.

Comment: For *saving* – suitable if *any* printable is intended to savable as well – this approach would avoid having to remember calling a parent function: `class P { public: void save(A& a) { /* add own saving work if need be */ doSave(a); } private: virtual void doSave(A& a) = 0; };` – unfortunately for swapping this is far less suitable...

Comment: @Aconcagua swap, save, load, print, equals, hash, ... A lot of common functions have to rely on the parent class. it's totally overkill to implement them empty in all the base classes. `sizeof` is irrelevant because the size of an empty class and the size of a class only having a char are both 1.

Comment: You have only two examples here, to swap and to save. What happens when you want to do more things? Suddenly all base-classes in your hierarchies will need to implement all functionality. It doesn't scale very well, and will make quite a mess. And if you're not sure if a base class can be saved, swapped, or whatever, and there's no documentation(!) then use the IntelliSense (or whatever) functionality of your environment to help you figure out if the base have a similar function or not. Or at the very least let the compiler give you errors when you try to use non-existing functions.

Comment: That might appear overkill – but what will happen if you indeed add some member? If there's no such base class function you will have to change *all* inheriting classes. If there are many of then not having to do so might quickly outweigh the price for the empty functions – or not, that's up to you to decide, but at least its worth thinking about twice ;)

Comment: I designate all my **interface** classes (which wouldn't need to do all those other things, because they have no state, and no members) by using a convention:  `namespace interface { class Printable { /*...*/ protected: virtual ~Printable() = default; }; }`  But it's just a convention.  If the language had `interface` as a keyword, I'd use that; but it doesn't, and this works well enough for my purposes.

Comment: My coworker reminded me that CRTP is better for this sort of thing.  No virtual function table stuff to make sure is taken into account.  C++23 will make it even better with `explicit this`.

Comment: As a sidenote, if you override a method, use the keyword `override`. And don't add `virtual` to an already virtual method.

Comment: @StefanRiedel yes. I migrate the code from C++98 to C++17. It's an habit I have to loose.

Comment: what can you do if parent do contain (private) state? parent class should implement those method if they want.